# How to retroactively make a java app fit different screens

Tags: java, resize, screen

I have a fairly large (6000 lines) java application with over 40 buttons etc. and fixed window size.
This is creating problem for people who wants to use it for some it is too small for others it is too large with no scrolling! How can I retroactively make it fit different screens?
Thanks

Comment: If you are using Swing make the window resizable and choose the right layout manager (probably gridbag)

Answer (score 0):

If yours is a Swing GUI (you have not mentioned this yet)

1. Don't use fixed size anything.
2. Use layout managers and nested JPanels to do the heavy work for you.
3. One comment to your question mentions using GridBagLayout, but I suggest that you avoid using this, that you instead use nested JPanels that use simpler layout managers, or use MigLayout.
4. To fill the Screen, set the extended state appropriately: `setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZE_BOTH)`